# #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new programmer. So I couldn't post images
I have 2 tables which I want to calculate
table `tarif` and `airdanlistrik`

Table `tarif` has 4 columns:

- `id_tarif`, `air`, `listrik`, `tanggal`

Table `airdanlistrik` has 6 columns:

- `id_airdanlistrik`, `id_rumah`, `posisi_air`, `posisi_listrik`,
  `id_maintenance`, `tanggal`

I tried following query, but it has an error

```
select 
  (
    select (d.posisi_air * t.air) as harga 
      from airdanlistrik d, tarif t 
     where t.tanggal = (select max(tanggal) from tarif) 
       and month(d.tanggal) = 1 
       and year(d.tanggal) = year(now())
  ) 
  - 
  (
    select (d.posisi_air * t.air) as harga 
      from airdanlistrik d,tarif t 
     where t.tanggal = (select max(tanggal) from tarif) 
       and month(d.tanggal) = 12 
       and year(d.tanggal) = year(now())-1
  ) 
from airdanlistrik d, tarif t 
group by d.id_rumah
```

This is error

```
 #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

I don't have enough idea on how to solve this error. please help me.

Comment: what's your expected result? maybe use `IN` at the place of `=`. Here: `t.tanggal = (select max(tanggal)...` replace by this: `t.tanggal IN (select max(tanggal)...`

Comment: you must use aggregate function such as SUM() , MAX() etc or you need to sure that your where condition must refer to only one row

Comment: i want that posisi_air in january for example * (multiplied by) last tarif reduce (-) to posisi_air in december * (multiplied by) last tarif on the condition that the same id_rumah

Comment: Are you expecting a single figure to be returned, or a row for each id_rumah?

Comment: i expect a row for each id_rumah

Answer (score 0):

Just to fix an error it is enough to add `LIMIT 1` to each of your subquery

```
select 
  (
    select (d.posisi_air * t.air) as harga 
      from airdanlistrik d, tarif t 
     where t.tanggal = (select max(tanggal) from tarif) 
       and month(d.tanggal) = 1 
       and year(d.tanggal) = year(now())
     limit 1
  ) 
  - 
  (
    select (d.posisi_air * t.air) as harga 
      from airdanlistrik d,tarif t 
     where t.tanggal = (select max(tanggal) from tarif) 
       and month(d.tanggal) = 12 
       and year(d.tanggal) = year(now())-1
     limit 1
  ) 
from airdanlistrik d, tarif t 
group by d.id_rumah
```

But it seems that the query is a bit wrong. Have you ever used JOINs?

Comment: It's basic feature of any SQL language. You can find a lot of materials about it. Ex. https://startpage.com/do/metasearch.pl?q=mysql%20join

Comment: sorry, why are all the same answer?

Comment: i mean, i want that posisi_air in january for example * (multiplied by) last tarif reduce (-) to posisi_air in december * (multiplied by) last tarif on the condition that the same id_rumah

Comment: I don't see your schema, data and a task. So i can't give you any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Really guessing what you want here as your description is very unclear.  An example of the data and the result you're trying to achieve would help to solve your issue.

```
SELECT d.id_rumah, (d.posisi_air * t.air - d1.posisi_air * t.air) as harga
FROM  airdanlistrik d 
INNER JOIN tarif t ON d.tangal = t.tangal AND t.tangal IN (SELECT MAX(tangal) FROM tarif)
INNER JOIN airdanlistrik d1 ON d.id_rumah = d1.id_rumah
WHERE month(d.tanggal) = 1 
AND year(d.tanggal) = year(now())
AND month(d1.tanggal) = 12 
AND year(d1.tanggal) = year(now())-1
```

Comment: error occured #1054 - Unknown column 'd.tangal' in 'on clause' and d.tanggal != t.tanggal.. airdanlistrik and tarif not relate